# Excel Stack Ranking Multiple Existing Ranks

Tags: excel, rank

I am trying to figure out the overall rank of a dataset of 93 employees. I have retrieved their ranks for each of the 5 categories I am considering, now I am needing to determine their overall rank based on these existing rankings. Below is a sample of the dataset I am working with:

```
Employee1   75  17  22  32  1   
Employee2   37  39  35  25  2   
Employee3   87  67  25  61  3   
Employee4   34  5   83  21  4   
Employee5   24  76  31  51  5   
Employee6   10  86  84  58  6   
Employee7   1   5   90  45  7   
Employee8   82  33  65  20  8   
Employee9   14  47  15  55  9   
Employee10  33  5   12  52  10  
Employee11  17  58  26  30  11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use SUMPRODUCT to "count" the number of sums greater than the current row sum:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(SUM(B2:F2)<=($B$2:$B$12+$C$2:$C$12+$D$2:$D$12+$E$2:$E$12+$F$2:$F$12)))
```

[image]